# How to send data over serial port without Operating system in c minimally?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, serial-port, vmware, hypervisor

I am trying to debug an hyper-visor I am writing, and I set up a serial port between two virtual machine in Vmware player(I am testing the hyper visor on a virtual machine with nested vt-x support). My question is how can I transfer data from the hyper visor to the serial port without the OS help(most of the software stack OS is not available when the hyper visor is on). I know I can see how other systems implement sending to a serial port and implement that way, but this beat the point of debugging because implementing a complete interface to serial port might take more time than finding the bugs manually. I only need to send one number, or a string so I am looking for the minimalist solution possible.

Until know I have been using netconsole in order to pass debugging information, but the bug I am facing right now, happens before the kernel get back the control, so netconsole is not able to send any data. If anyone have a better idea on how to pass the debugging information other than using serial port I would love to hear that.

Right now I have came into that Resource https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/8250_UART_Programming , that might be relevant to my question, but I would love if someone can elaborate, sending data through using out, is working, but the data order is messed up and cant be used for debugging, so, so far it dosent help.

Comment: Any OS kernel or boot loader initialization code would be good enough to start with.

Comment: *"I set up a serial port between two virtual machine"* -- A single serial port cannot serve two machines.  A serial port is a peripheral device, and not a communications link.  If you set up a serial *link* between two machines, then you need two serial ports, one on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to set up and use a serial port for diagnostic output, and I predict that you will find it immensely useful. To start with, you can use it just for debug output, but since it can be bidirectional, you can extend it as needed to do such things as dump and modify memory and registers (both hypervisor state and guest state).

To set up a serial port, first you have to find the base address. If it is COM1, then it is 3f8, so I'll use that as an example. To initialize the port, write these values, using the OUT instruction:

```
3fb = 80  // LCR = DLAB
3f8 = 1   // DLL = divisor low (115200 baud)
3f9 = 0   // DLM = divisor high
3fb = 3   // LCR = 8/1/n
3f9 = 0   // IER = 0
3fa = 1   // FCR = FIFO enable
3fc = 3   // MCR = terminal ready | request to send
```

To send a character, read from 3fd (LSR) using the IN instruction and loop until bit 5 is set (THR empty). Then write the character to 3f8 (THR).

Of course, a serial port driver can be much more sophisticated than this, but this is enough to get it going.